# Problem in assigning a value in DropdownList

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I already get the value of the item key (Insurance Category). However, I can't seem to put it back to Insurance Category. How will I assign it to Insurance Category? I need this in order for me to save/add a new Insurance Entry.

Please give me an example on how it will be assigned to the Insurance Category.

Please check my codes below:

```
List<Value> lsValue = oInsurance.Category.ValueList;
foreach (Value item in lstValue)
{
    if (item.Key.ToString() == drpCategory.SelectedValue)
    {
        oInsurance.Category.value = item.Key;// error here
    }
}
```

Dropdownlist code:

private void InsuranceCategorySource()
    {

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables.Add("Source");
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Desc", Type.GetType("System.String"));


    Insurance oInsurance = new Insurance();
    List<Value> lstValue = oInsurance.Category.ValueList;
    foreach (Value item in lstValue)
    {

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = item.Key.ToString();
        dr[1] = item.Value.ToString();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    drpCategory.DataSource = ds;
    drpCategory.DataMember = "Source";
    drpCategory.DataTextField = "Desc";
    drpCategory.DataValueField = "ID";
    drpCategory.DataBind();

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error you get and what is the Value class that you are using?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object

Comment: The error message you've posted is not complete, which is the object one.. `oInsurance.Category.value` or `item.Key`? Try converting `item.Key` first before assigning it to `oInsurance.Category.value`.

Comment: If the type of .value is string then you can change like this oInsurance.Category.value = item.Key.ToString()

Comment: @subhashi, it's not a string type or interger..

Comment: Then what is the data type of `oInsurance.Category.value` and `item.Key`?

Comment: oInsurance.Category (InsuranceCategory type) its a read only..

Comment: Then you can't assign any data to `oInsurance.Category` since it is read only.

Comment: I can insert data as long the type of data i insert is INsuranceCtegory not a string or integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be recommended if you set the `DisplayMember` of the Dropdown to the Value and the `ValueMember` of the Dropdown to the Key.

If you set the `DisplayMember` and the `ValueMember` of the list correctly your code would work.

Since you're using ASP.NET properties to set correctly would be [DataTextField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield.aspx) and [DataValueField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield.aspx) in ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if i am getting it wrong. You are first checking for they key with the selected value of Drop down list and then based on that you are trying to enter its "value" to insurance category?

```
if (item.Key.ToString() == drpCategory.SelectedValue)     //Check
    {
        oInsurance.Category.value = item.Value;           
       // I think it should be value    
       //instead of key which will be of type String.
    }
```